# Creating a.bat file to delete a particular row on any application

Tags: batch-file, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a .bat script file to `SELECT` and `DELETE` following row-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

The above row can appear in any application like Notepad, MS Word, Any other application's text area etc.

So, I will create a keyboard shortcut of the .bat file and whenever I run that keyboard shortcut, it will search for the above row in the particular opened application and then delete the entire row.

It is same like we select any string using mouse and then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on keyboard to delete it.

As a solution-
I can write Macro, but it will not work for all applications, for example a web application having text area.

Comment: Not going to happen with a batch file. Batch Files cannot interact with a graphical user interface. Wish I had a dollar for every time I have posted that comment.

Comment: @Squashman
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Squashman
Could you please suggest me any other way to do this task ?

Comment: What you are looking for is [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no practical solution that meets your criteria. An alternative would be to remove the lines directly from the files prior to running NotePad or other apps. Take a look at spew from `help findstr`.  For each file that has that line at the top, rename the file, read it, discard the first line and then write the remaining contents back to a new file with the original file name.

Answer (score 0):

The  line is the XML declaration, and should appear in all XML files. 
The simplest way to remove it is to create an XSL transformation that removes the declaration:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can create an [applet that allows you to run this stylesheet](https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/resources/) via drag&drop.

Removing the XML declaration is not recommended, because it contains information that is important to read the XML file correctly. It's not recommended to open XML files in Word, because that runs the risk of modifying the XML via Word's various auto-layout features that will make the XML invalid (=not readable in XML applications).